# Getting error Secret version <GUID> has no stage for rotation of secret while rotating secret in AWS Secret Manager from lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager, secret-manager

I have created the secter in AWS Secret Manager using single user rotation policy.
Now I want to test the generated lambda function. While testing lambda function , I am providing args as shown below:

```
   {
  "Step": "setSecret",
  "SecretId": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxx:secret:test_qa-ldpjrx",
  "ClientRequestToken": "72921c2c-df3b-11eb-ba80-0242ac130004"
}
```

where i generated "ClientRequestToken": "72921c2c-df3b-11eb-ba80-0242ac130004" token from https://www.uuidgenerator.net/version1 and paste it.

On execution of test case , I am getting below issue:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Secret version 72921c2c-df3b-11eb-ba80-0242ac130004 has no stage for rotation of secret arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxx:secret:test_qa-ldpjrx",
  "errorType": "ValueError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 63, in lambda_handler\n    raise ValueError(\"Secret version %s has no stage for rotation of secret %s.\" % (token, arn))\n"
  ]
}
```

This is console output for describe secret:

```
aws secretsmanager describe-secret --secret-id test_qa


{
        "ARN": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxx:secret:test_qa-ldpjrx",
        "Name": "test_qa",
        "RotationEnabled": true,
        "RotationLambdaARN": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:10582323238:function:SecretsManagertest_qa",
        "RotationRules": {
            "AutomaticallyAfterDays": 30
        },
        "LastRotatedDate": "2021-07-07T21:22:10.689000+05:30",
        "LastChangedDate": "2021-07-07T21:22:10.698000+05:30",
        "LastAccessedDate": "2021-07-07T05:30:00+05:30",
        "Tags": [],
        "VersionIdsToStages": {
            "aeee838a-6719-4d6a-be89-515a205ea470": [
                "AWSCURRENT"
            ],
            "d58a7df7-77ce-40e1-ad9c-2bbc9f9da98c": [
                "AWSPREVIOUS"
            ]
        },
        "CreatedDate": "2021-07-07T19:51:32.487000+05:30"
    }
```

Where exactly I am missing ?

Comment: Running into this myself. Did you find a solution?